# How to move down a cell while in a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a loop where I want it to continue to loop until the active cell is empty. If the active cell is not empty I want it to copy the contents of cell "C2" (from a different sheet) into cell "D5".
The Active Cell range is "G5" and the destination is "D5" I want both to offset so check "G6" and paste to "D6".
And so on until the Active Cell("G6" in this example) is empty and stop the loop.

I have provided some code which should help with what ive tried to explain above. I just want the loop to check the Active Cell is not empty and then paste the contents to the destination. Most basic terms every time it loops I want the "D5" to change to D6".

```
Sub FormatFile_Click()

    Dim raw As Worksheet
    Dim formula As Worksheet

    Set raw = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw")
    Set formula = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formula")

    Range("G5").Select

      ' Set Do loop to stop when an empty cell is reached.
      Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
         formula.Range("C2").Copy Destination:=raw.Range("D5")
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      Loop
End sub
```

Comment: Which sheet is this ? `Range("G5").Select`

Comment: Range("G5").Select is from worksheet 'raw'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Something like this should do the Job for You.**

```
Sub FormatFile_Click()

    Dim raw As Worksheet
    Dim formula As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer

    Set raw = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw")
    Set formula = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formula")

    For i = 5 To raw.Range("G5:G" & raw.Range("G5").End(xlDown).Row).Cells.Count + 5

         formula.Range("C2").Copy Destination:=raw.Cells(i, 4)

    Next

End Sub
```

**Always try to avoid usage of Select & Activate in VBA**

Comment: im getting an error on line  For i = 5 To raw.Range("G5:G" & raw.Range("G5").End(xlDown)).Cells.Count - "Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed

Comment: Try Again. I forgot to Add `.Row` ... I have added it now

Answer (score 0):

You could skip the loop and go much faster with something like this: (untested)

```
dim fla as string
fla = worksheets("formula").range("c2").formulaR1C1
worksheets("raw").range("G5:G60000").Specialcells(xlCellTypeConstants).formulaR1C1 = fla
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately using While or Until with range is a bit complicated. I would suggest using the following:

```
      Dim raw As Worksheet
      Dim formulaSht As Worksheet
  Dim i as Long
  dim Idest as Long

      Set raw = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw")
   (I changed the worksheet formula to FormulaSht just to make differentiate it from the formula command)
      Set formulaSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formula")
  'instead of selecting the range define it in the loop!
  ' g5 is cells(5,7)
     ' Range("G5").Select
  i = 5
  'I'm setting the destination row as 2 ii (feel free to change it, also you can modify the 'column number, for the below I'll match column d = 4, if you want the copied row to be the same as the pasted row than you can use the same variable for both as save the tiniest bit of memory
  Idest = 2

        ' Set Do loop to stop when an empty cell is reached.
        Do Until Cells(i,7) = ""
           formulaSht.cells(i,7).Copy Destination:=raw.cells(Idest,4)
      i = i+1
  Idest = Idest + 1
        Loop
  End sub
```